# Does AsyncStorage data made available to other apps in the AppGroup?

Tags: ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make AsyncStorage values available to other apps in my app group. In particular, I have a Keyboard extension that I want to access user data that is retrieved in the core app.

My suspicion is that it isn't supported, and if it isn't, consider this a feature request.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to access AsyncStorage values as far as I am aware from native code. If you need to do it, consider using `Settings` module instead that persists to NSUserDefaults.